# How can you programmatically tell the CPython interpreter to enter interactive mode when done?

Tags: cpython, python

If you invoke the cpython interpreter with the -i option, it will enter the interactive mode upon completing any commands or scripts it has been given to run.  Is there a way, within a program to get the interpreter to do this even when it has not been given -i? The obvious use case is in debugging by interactively inspecting the state when an exceptional condition has occurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the PYTHONINSPECT environment variable.  This can also be done in the script itself:

```
import os
os.environ["PYTHONINSPECT"] = "1"
```

For debugging unexpected exceptions, you could also use this nice recipe http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65287/

Answer (score 14):

You want the [code module](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import code    
code.interact("Enter Here")
```

Answer (score 3):

The [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65287/) metioned in the other answer using `sys.excepthook`, sounds like what you want. Otherwise, you could run `code.interact` on program exit:

```
import code
import sys
sys.exitfunc = code.interact
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this that I know of is:

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

which allows access to variables in the current scope and brings you the full power of IPython.